# No such method exception in RangeSeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar, nosuchmethoderror

I've referred [RangeSeekBar](http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) to implement Seekbar with two thumbs.

I'm getting following error in log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: RangeSeekBar(Context,AttributeSet)
```

and if I try to add  following method in `RangeSeekBar.java`, I'm getting error as : *The blank final field numberType may not have been initialized*

```
public RangeSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
 super(context, attrs);
 }
```

I'm banging my head from few hours, but haven't find any fruitful solution.

Any help appreciated.
Any other way to implement SeekBar With Two thumb is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any custom view in android should have a constructor like you wrote. So, keep it. The problem is, you have a final field in your class, that should be initialized in constructor. So, remove final modifier from that variable, or set it to some value in constructor.

**About RangeSeekBar:**
this class is using generic types for detecting what type of number you want to use (float, double, or just int values). So, do not put this as a view in xml layout file, and add it in code like this:

```
someViewGroup.addView(new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 10, context));
```

which `someViewGroup` is the view you want to put `RangeSeekBar` in it. (its parent).

Comment: how to select  maximum of `30` range  between  `1` to `100` I am using `RangeSeekBarView` for trimming video  for this example https://github.com/HemendraGangwar/VideoTrimmingLikeWhatsapp